# Data ingestion with HTTP Event Collector in Splunk Web vs data ingestion using Splunk REST API

Tags: splunk, splunk-api

I am new to Splunk and have been exploring it's features. I have tried to ingest some dummy data into Splunk Web using the Http Event Collector(HEC). I wanted to know if there is any other REST API available in splunk for data input. If so, then what is the difference between HEC and the other REST API provided by Splunk. Thanking in advance for any understanding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Splunk's REST API is more for managing Splunk than for getting data into Splunk.  You should continue to use HEC for ingesting data.